# Grails ApplicationContext.xml grailsResourceLoader

Tags: xml, grails

I’m trying to get a Project running on Tomcat7 that requires some Plugins and is written in Grails.

Creating a -war with the command **grails prod war** results in no Errors.
But if i add the app to my Tomcat7server it dose not get executed.

The log file of my tomcat7 reviels that there must be something wrong with my ApplicationContext.xml.

```
2014-07-01 15:22:22,325 [http-bio-8080-exec-87] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'grailsResourceLoader' while setting bean property 'grailsResourceLoader'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
Cannot find class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean] 
for bean with name 'grailsResourceLoader' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean
```

My ApplicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
        <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
        <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean">
        <property name="grailsResourceHolder" ref="grailsResourceHolder" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceHolder" scope="prototype" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsResourceHolder">
        <property name="resources">
              <value>classpath*:**/grails-app/**/*.groovy</value>
        </property>
    </bean>    

   <bean id="characterEncodingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
        <property name="encoding">
          <value>utf-8</value>
        </property>
   </bean>      
</beans>
```

My research showed me that with the new Grails 2.4.0 some things have been deleted like the Holder stuff.

but now i dont know what to do with that  Do I remove the lines ? Do I need to replace them or even delete them ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What I did then upgraded my own applications.
At first, I've created new grails application and compared to mine - what added and removed.
At second, many troubles you may encounter with old plugins.
Then you may just wait or try to patch and send code to plugin developers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Simply,**

Remove `grailsResourceLoader` bean reference (the line below) from `applicationContext.xml`.

```
<property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
```

and remove it from the property of `grailsApplication` bean

and you will have:

```
<bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
    <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the section "Changes To applicationContext.xml" - http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

Basically remove the reference of ***grailsResourceLoader*** and corresponding bean declaration form applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss please.

(copy over the applicationContext.xml from the 2.4 distro into your 
grails app)