# Deploy grails 2.5.5 app to tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, grails, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Grails 2.5.5 app to Tomcat 7 (running on Ubuntu server). I used the command `war -stacktrace -verbose` in Intellij 14 to create the war file. Inside my `target` directory it successfully created the war file, let's call it `myapp-0.1.war`. Then in the terminal (I'm using Linux Mint) I used the following command to copy it to my server (I substitued my details in the example below, like `mypcusername`, `myserverusername` and `123.123.123.123`)

```
rsync -rtvW --delete /home/mypcusername/NetbeansProjects/myapp/target/myapp-0.1.war/ myserverusername@123.123.123.123:/home/myserverusername/myapp-0.1.war/
```

Don't worry about the `NetbeansProjects` part of the above command either, it was originally a Netbeans project. Then I used `sudo cp -a myapp-0.1.war/ /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/` followed by `sudo rm -R ROOT` to delete the original `ROOT` directory. Then I ran `sudo service tomcat7 restart` and this is where the problem is. The logs gave me the following:

```
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1734 ms
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Sep 03, 2017 10:23:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Sep 03, 2017 10:24:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Sep 03, 2017 10:24:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
2017-09-03 10:24:26,325 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: grails/plugin/cache/CacheConfigArtefactHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class grails.plugin.cache.CacheConfigArtefactHandler)
    at CacheGrailsPlugin.<init>(CacheGrailsPlugin.groovy:49)
    ... 5 more
2017-09-03 10:24:26,330 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: grails/plugin/cache/CacheConfigArtefactHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class grails.plugin.cache.CacheConfigArtefactHandler)
    at CacheGrailsPlugin.<init>(CacheGrailsPlugin.groovy:49)
    ... 5 more
2017-09-03 10:24:26,332 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [CacheGrailsPlugin]!
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: grails/plugin/cache/CacheConfigArtefactHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class grails.plugin.cache.CacheConfigArtefactHandler)
    at CacheGrailsPlugin.<init>(CacheGrailsPlugin.groovy:49)
    ... 5 more
Sep 03, 2017 10:24:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 03, 2017 10:24:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 03, 2017 10:24:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 03, 2017 10:24:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 43228 ms
```

**EDIT** Thanks to suricatta, I followed his instructions by creating and chowning all the directories which made all those warnings go away. I'm updating the logs.

Since originally asking the question I realised that I never actually copied a .war file to my server because when I tried to extract the files it would tell me something like "you can't extract a directory", I then noticed that it created an empty directory called myapp-0.1.war every time I used `rsync -rtvW --delete /home/mypcusername/NetbeansProjects/myapp/target/myapp-0.1.war/ myserverusername@123.123.123.123:/home/myserverusername/myapp-0.1.war/`.

I then used `scp /home/mypcusername/NetBeansProjects/myapp/target/myapp-0.1.war myserverusername@41.185.91.194:/home/myserverusername` which did actually copy the war to my server. After extracting the actual files this time in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT I restarted Tomcat and that then gave me the above logs. When I go to 123.123.123.123:8080 I get a blank page with a javascript error saying `GET http://123.123.123.123:8080/ 404 (Not Found)` and I tried different variations like `<ip>:8080/myapp` and `<ip>:8080/myapp/home` all with the same result.

I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511939/grails-applicationcontext-xml-grailsresourceloader) answer but that doesn't seem to  apply to me coz I don't have the same values in my applicationContext.xml that the OP of that question has. Let my know if I need to post my applicationContext.xml.

Comment: I don't know if those _Problem with directory_ warnings are responsible for _This page can't be found_, but I resolved them by creating those directories like `mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes` etc. Also don't forget to give permissions `chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes`.

Comment: I would guess the webapp deployed just fine in the dir "myapp-0.1". What happens when you open "123.123.123.123:8080/myapp-0.1"? "It works!" is the default welcome page from apache httpd, not from tomcat.

Comment: looks like your project and/or grails has been compiled for java 8 and your Ubuntu server runns Java 7.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Nope, checked it out. Here's what's on my server: `java version "1.8.0_144"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a new project, copied all my stuff from the project I was trying to deploy into the the new project and deployed it, which solved the problem I was having.